# How to fetch the data from a collection of optionals?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have a method returning a collection of products:

```
Collection<Product> getProducts() { ... }
```

Each product may have a guarantee. But it is not required.

```
interface Product {
    Optional<Guarantee> getGuarantee();
}
```

Now I need to go through all the products and check if the quarantees have expired. The non-expired ones should be collected into a list.

This is what I do:

```
List<Optional<Guarantee>> optionalGar = getProducts().stream()
      .map(f -> f.getGuarantee()).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Guarantee> gar = optionalGar.stream()    
      .map(op -> op.orElse(null))             
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .filter(g -> !g.hasExpired())
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there any way to avoid using `.orElse(null)`?

(Replacing it by `op.get()` would cause an exception in case the optional is empty)

*P.S: I'm free to chose between Java 8 and Java 9 so both solutions (not sure if the'll be different) are welcome*

Answer (score 7):

**Java 8**

```
List<Guarantee> expiredGuarantees = getProducts().stream()
                                                 .map(Product::getGuarantee)    
                                                 .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                                                 .map(Optional::get)
                                                 .filter(not(Guarantee::hasExpired))
                                                 .collect(toList());
```

**Java 9**

Java9 has got `Optional::stream`. So you can replace filtering and mapping with single `flatMap`:

```
List<Guarantee> expiredGuarantees = getProducts().stream()
                                                 .map(Product::getGuarantee)    
                                                 .flatMap(Optional::stream)
                                                 .filter(not(Guarantee::hasExpired))
                                                 .collect(toList());
```

**Note**

Java 8 does not have `Predicates.not` method. It's included since 11th version only.

By adding the following method to your project you'll be able to use it with the solutions above.

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> not(Predicate<T> predicate) { 
    return predicate.negate();
}
```

**Update**

Although this is not the [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) community, here are some notes on your code:

- By combining the two pipelines into a single your code will be cleaner (in this particular case).
- Prefer a `method reference` over a `lambda` when possible
- Give appropriate names to your variables so you'll make your code easier to maintain